# How to post a tweet to Twitter AND get its id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I have the Twitter API installed into a Rails app via this brilliant gem: https://github.com/sferik/twitter. I've been posting some test tweets on my feed and all was fine until I realized that I need to also grab the tweet that is sent out and display it on the site.

Use case: When a user signs up, a tweet is sent out. I'd like to display the tweet that was sent out so that they know they've been tweeted.

Is there anyway I can get the id of a tweet when I do `$twitter_api.update(new_user_tweet)`?

`new_user_tweet` would be `"We are glad to welcome user12450 to the party!"`. You get the idea.

Comment: I doubt it, I don't think twitter gives a response to the api call withanything that would help.

Comment: <code>twitter_api.user_timeline("HiThere").map { |t| t.text }.grep(/username/).first</code> is what I'm going to have to use. If anyone knows anything better, would be glad to know about it.